# Using Filter inside a Function - Optimizing the function code

Tags: r, function, dplyr, filter, tidyverse

I often load data from which I need to filter a select number of variables, which are always the same. The column containing them, however, isn't always identical. Here's a sample that reflects my data:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1:50),
                 variable = sample(c("v1", "v2", "v3", "v4","v5","v6","v7"), 50, replace = T),
                 value = sample(c(80:150), 50, replace = T))


> df %>%
+   head()
  id variable value
1  1       v3   138
2  2       v5    89
3  3       v2    98
4  4       v7    84
5  5       v1   144
6  6       v2   105
```

Using help from posts on stackoverflow, I've come up with the following function, and above it I've writing the piece of code I'd usually write:

```
df %>%
  filter(variable %in% c('v1','v2','v3','v4'))


my_filter <- function(df,x){
  df %>%
    filter(x %in% c('v1','v2','v3','v4'))
}
```

Now if I used it:

```
df %>%
  my_filter(df$variable)

> head(df %>%
+   my_filter(df$variable))
  id variable value
1  3       v2    98
2  5       v1   144
3  6       v2   105
4  8       v2   128
5 10       v1   122
6 11       v1   131
```

This works fine, and will save me a small amount of time everytime I repeat this task. I was wondering though, if there was a way to avoid having to type in `df$variable` in the second argument of the function, and obtain a solution using chaining only. Something that I could then use like this:

```
df %>%
 my_filter(variable)
```

Comment: just replace `x` with `{{x}}` in `my_filter`

Comment: Why not just do `df %>% my_filter() %>% head()`?

Comment: @det if you answer my post directly, I'll mark your answer as solved.

Comment: @mhovd that didn't seem to work, unless I first use det's solution.

Comment: I didn't realize you wanted to pass the column name as a string, in that case you can also use `!!as.name(x)` instead of `{{x}}`. However, there are very few practical differences between the two.